# scrapy to csv change data format

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been scraping http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters for fighters data. When I scrape fighter record, everything looks normal when I run the command lines. However, when I try to convert the scraped data into a csv file using

```
scrapy runspider {spider_file} -o fighters.csv -t csv
```

something strange happens: certain data becomes date format. for example, the original record 10-16-1 becomes date format 16/01/2001

How can I prevent this format conversion to happen? These reformat doesn't happen consistently.

Comment: You sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48077351/16815044) isn't the answer here?

Comment: ah yes. Thank you for pointing out